# Linq and SQL Injection in my asp.net core project I am learning

Tags: linq, asp.net-core

I am learning asp.net core and I am using some Linq to pass to my razor view page.

The page has a text box on for search terms, and also a category selection dropdown.

The code below shows some of the parts that make up the actual search - are the sections commented as vulnerable a bad way to do things and open to SQL injection?

If so what is a better way to handle it?

I have looked at things like FromSQL etc but I don't want to use that unless I have to.

```
// For search textbox and search category DDL in web page
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string SearchString { get; set; }

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string CategoryString { get; set; }


// In my page's .cs file .....
List<KnowledgeBaseListVM> kblist = new List<KnowledgeBaseListVM>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CategoryString) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
{

    // _context is my db context
    var q = (from kb in _context.KnowledgeBase
             join c in _context.KnowledgeBaseCategory on kb.CategoryId equals c.Id
             orderby kb.Title
             select new
             {
                 kb.Id,
                 kb.DateCreated,
                 kb.Title,
                 Category = c.Title,
                 kb.Text,
                 kb.CategoryId
             }).ToList();


    // SearchString - Vulnerable?
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
    {
        q = q.Where(s => s.Category.ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToLower()) || s.Title.ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToLower()) || s.Text.ToLower().Contains(SearchString.ToLower())).ToList();
    }

    // Search Category - Vulnerable?
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CategoryString))
    {
        q = q.Where(s => s.CategoryId == int.Parse(CategoryString)).ToList();
    }

}
```

S

Comment: Look at the generated SQL and you'll see that all search strings are parametrized. No SQL injection involved.

Comment: You want to avoid using string concatenation if you use FromSql(). It's OK if you use string interpolation. That being said, I'd avoid using FromSql() altogether and use the framework as is.